# creating a file through trigger in db2 9.7 LUW

Tags: db2-luw

Can i create a file (within the db2 server) through a trigger. And the file have information of the action that is activating it?
ps: i am using Linux environment and the db2 version is 9.7

Comment: You can, but this may not be a very good idea.

Comment: well that is kind of the requirement...could you direct me to some documents where i can check for it?

Comment: Check out the `UTL_FILE` module description in the DB2 manual. I assume you already know about `CREATE TRIGGER`.